# Wait for abstract function to finish c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, abstract

I have two class (CLASS1 and CLASS2), from CLASS1 i call an abstract method and i need wait to end of it and show a message "End Process...", how can i solve this?

CLASS-1:

```
public abstract partial class CLASS1 : Form
{
    public CLASS1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start Process ABSMethod1");
        ABSMethod1("var1", "var2");
        Console.WriteLine("End Process ABSMethod1");

        Console.WriteLine("Start Process ABSMethod2");
        ABSMethod2(1, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("End Process ABSMethod2");
    }

    protected abstract void ABSMethod1(String var1, String var2);
    protected abstract void ABSMethod2(int var1, int var2);
}
```

CLASS-2:

```
class CLASS2: CLASS1
{
    protected override void ABSMethod1(String var1, String var2)
    {
        if (var1 == "test")
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach<clssmt>(items, item =>
                {
                    /* ... */
                });
            });
        }
        //if i use Task.Wait() freezes UI.
    }

    protected override void ABSMethod2(int var1, int var2)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach<clssmt>(items, item =>
            {
                /* ... */
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I solve this problem using `protected virtual async Task` and `await`, but i'm not sure if it is the best solution. And if i use this solution, the message "End Procces" is shown little before that Task is finished.

Comment: If you are on .Net 4.5 and up you should make your abstract methods return a task and await them in a aynsc method calling them. However you can't await inside a constructor. This is a good blog on using async/await with Task.Run: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html. Also try to avoid calling overridable methods from constructors as this could result in some very unpredictable behavior. Especially when you are not the only one using your codebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i need wait to end of it and show a message "End Process...", how can i solve this?

You expose those executed `Task`'s to the caller. You also don't invoke them via your constructor, but via an initialization method:

```
protected abstract Task FirstMethodAsync(string var1, string var2);
protected abstract Task SecondMethodAsync(int var1, int var2);

public async Task InitializeAsync()
{
     Console.WriteLine("Start Process ABSMethod1");
     await FirstMethodAsync("var1", "var2");
     Console.WriteLine("End Process ABSMethod1");

     Console.WriteLine("Start Process ABSMethod2");
     await SecondMethodAsync(1, 2);
     Console.WriteLine("End Process ABSMethod2");
}
```

Comment: But, in "ABSMethod1" and "ABSMethod2", what return? i need return a new Task? how? thanks

Comment: @Manux22 You return the `Task` created by `Task.Run`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i'm sleepy. But, if i need interrupt function? normally i use `return;`, but in this case i need return a Task, how can i solve this?

Comment: @Manux22 What do you mean by interrupt function?

Comment: when i need stop the function process y use `return;` similar to `break;` in a loop. In"FirstMethodAsync" i can't use `return;` because i need return a Task, i try with `return null;` but this provoke an NullReferenceException. See conditional in the first post.

Comment: if var1 is equals to "test" return a task, but if "var1" is not equals? what return?

Comment: @Manux22 You can use `return;` in an async method that returns a `Task` without specifying what to return.

Comment: @Manux `await` will implicitly generate a `Task` for you. No need to create one yourself.